# "plist" doesn't load from iPhone unit-test class

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, plist

I'm trying to unit-test code for loading and querying data from plist file. I'm loading data with code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"availableshops" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *arrayOfShops = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

When testing app in simulator and on the device everything work. BUT when I run unit test, code "`[arrayOfShops count]`" always returns "`0`".

I have the same files in "Copy Bundle Resources", "Compile Sources" and "Link Binary With Libraries" for main target and unit-test target. I've also tried with and without main target as "Direct Dipendencies" for unit-test target.

Does anyone have idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `[NSBundle mainBundle]` with Xcode Unit Test, that will work if you use this instead:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"availableshops" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *arrayOfShops = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220526/27951). Apparently `mainBundle` doesn't work in the context of a test bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the plist root element is an array?  Posting the plist might help.

You could also try this:

```
NSArray* shopsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"availableshops.plist"];
```